# Is it necessary to set variable = null in Activity's onDestory( ) method?

Tags: android

In my company's android project (10k+ users), we set variable = null in almost every Activity's `onDestory()` method. The code is like below:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    //mImageView = null;
    if(pagerAdapter != null){
        pagerAdapter.clear();
        pagerAdapter = null;
    }
    if(mediaList != null){
        mediaList.clear();
        mediaList = null;
    }
    viewPager = null;
    clickedMsg = null;
    instance = null;
    msg = null;
    //System.gc();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Is it necessary? Thank you for answering my question~

Comment: I would NOT do that. Seems unnecessary.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is someone is afraid that a different function is also going to clear the list. Which I'm not sure why that is such a big problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case its not necessary. And take note :

> **There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's
>   hosting process without calling this method** (or any others) in it, so
>   it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around
>   after the process goes away.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29).

### So when should I nullify in `onDestroy()`?

When there is reference that holds the activity from being Garbage collected. Like for example a static variable that holds an activity in its arguments or by its method. Also Some of the Singleton design pattern does this with poorly implemented code, so be careful on that and release it through `onDestroy().`

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary, it will be recycled automatically by GC when activity destroy. Only when use special resources like BitMap or IOStream,need special recycling process.